# Pandas: Take an average of rows with matching values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've tried several ideas posted on the forums but none is quite working. I have a dataframe of product identifiers and prices. I have already narrowed the df to only where the same product has more than one price in the larger database. Now I want to create a new column that will be the average price of a given product. I.e.:

```
ID          Price
ABC1        101.45
XYZ2        88.12
ABC1        99.24
XYZ2        82.99
ABC1        105.00
```

The output I want is as such:

```
ID          Price          AvgPx
ABC1        101.45         101.897
XYZ2        88.12          85.556
ABC1        99.24          101.897
XYZ2        82.99          85.556
ABC1        105.00         101.897
```

I've tried various versions of groupby and for loops and nothing quite works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your dataframe is indexed by 'ID'?

Comment: No sorry I have an index just didn't put it in my sample dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the other solutions offered work great, I would argue that using `transform` here leads to nice clean easy to read code:

```
df['AvgPx'] = df.groupby('ID')['Price'].transform('mean')

>>> df
     ID   Price       AvgPx
0  ABC1  101.45  101.896667
1  XYZ2   88.12   85.555000
2  ABC1   99.24  101.896667
3  XYZ2   82.99   85.555000
4  ABC1  105.00  101.896667
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an aggregate version of the dataframe, then use merge to join your original dataframe with your aggregate.

```
agg_df = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Price'].mean().rename(columns={'Price': 'AvgPx'})


df = df.merge(agg_df)

ID   Price       AvgPx
0  ABC1  101.45  101.896667
1  ABC1   99.24  101.896667
2  ABC1  105.00  101.896667
3  XYZ2   88.12   85.555000
4  XYZ2   82.99   85.555000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
avg = df.groupby('ID').Price.mean()
df.join(avg, on='ID', rsuffix='Avg')
```

It would be nicer to say `df['AvgPx'] = avg.reindex(df.ID)`, but that doesn't work because `reindex()` requires a unique series.